# Calling PowerShell function from command line

Tags: powershell, cmd

Given the following `say-hello.ps1` file on my file system:

```
function SayHello()
{
    return "Hello World!"
}
```

called on the command line like so (it will eventually run as a Windows Scheduled Task):

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "& { c:\say-hello.ps1; SayHello }"
```

Why am I getting the following result?

```
SayHello : The term 'SayHello' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:33
+ & { c:\say-hello.ps1; SayHello }
+                       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SayHello:String) [], CommandNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scope of the script file `c:\say-hello.ps1` ends when the script terminates. You can dot source the file (note the `.` before the PS1) if you would like its contents to run within the current scope -- the script block enclosed with curlies `{...}`:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "& { . c:\say-hello.ps1; SayHello }"
```

Comment: I have a function calling from powershell like this:
Expand-ZIPFile –File “E:\MYDOC.zip” –Destination “E:\New MYDOC”

It's fine by powershell but while doing from command line by the above method it gives error "Missing expression after unary operator '_'. Any suggestion.

Comment: You seem to have both "prettified" dashes and quotes in your example: `–`, `“`, `”`. I would try with `cmd` again using the ASCII `-` and `"`.

Comment: I have a function:

function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
   $shell = new-object -com shell.application
   $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
 foreach($item in $zip.items())
 {
$shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
}
}